# How resolve null value in toMap

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I have a problem, practically when I select two time slots within a week and generate them through a button all ok, but then when I go to delete a day of the week and then click again on the button "generate slots", I choose my week (where I had two days but now I have only one) I get the error on  line 100 of code that I place there:
[image]

Comment: What's your error?

Comment: @sigur null pointer exception

Comment: @sigur Hi it work now, thanks, but now the problem is a exsisting item (I have 2 iten now i  have delete one item). The error is: de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.ModelSavingException: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: query; SQL []; Duplicate entry '8796093074981-2022-05-02 22:00:00

Comment: I suggest to you to open a new question with the details to a better understanding of the problem and its cause. @mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the shared '100' line you basically telling to JDK compiler: for each object into list create a map entry with:

- key the value of getDay from the object
- value the object itself

The JDK converts it to:

- key = `object.getDay()`
- value = `object`

In your list there are items which are `null`, example: `[{obj1}, {obj2}, null, ...]`.

This causes the `TimeSlot::getDay` to be `null.getDay()` in some cases. If you need to put `null` as key, you could transform it from `TimeSlot::getDay` to `o -> o != null ? o.getDay() : null`.

If you do not need `null` as key value, you could filter them before collecting, example adding: `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`.

Check [what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for response but not work, I have "null pointer exception)